# Need an ASP MVC database guru to properly initialize relationships

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a one-to-one relationship between a client and an address. By my understanding I have to tinker with the `OnModelCreating` method which I have. Right now I'm ready to give my application a go but I need to properly initialize my database; but I'm getting an error.

The main plan is to create a client first and then later on create an address to associate with them.

Here's my context class:

```
public class VolumeV2Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GiftCard> GiftCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }              

         // use if you need to drop the database
         static VolumeV2Context(){

     // use if need to reset the models
     // Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<VolumeV2Context>());

     // use to reset whole database tables
      Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<VolumeV2Context>());

    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Clients>()
            .HasOptional(j => j.Address)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasRequired(j => j.client)
            .WithRequiredDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true) ;                           


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string City {get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Province {get; set;}

    public virtual Clients client { get; set; }

}
public class Clients
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone ")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address {get; set;}

    [Display(Name = "Email List")]
    public Boolean EmailList { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Hair Type")]
    public string HairType { get; set; }        

   [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In my first call to the database, which is in the main index method

```
return View(db.Clients.Take(25).ToList());
```

It returns an error saying:

> *Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.Clients_client_Id' on table 'Addresses' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint. See previous errors.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have bi-directional cascading deletes. In other words, deleting a client will delete an address which will delete a client which will delete an address... you get the picture.

Just looking at your data model, wouldn't it make more sense *not* to delete the client if his/her address were deleted (people move all the time :-)). Or is there a reason why deleting an address should also wipe out the client (after all, your data model does say address is optional....)

If you comment out the lines:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
    .HasRequired(j => j.client)
    .WithRequiredDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true) ;
```

, or make the WillCascadeOnDelete false, does it work?

Another option is to turn the cascade delete convention off completely...

```
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

but I don't think that's what you're wanting to do here...

Comment: Thank you for the great visualization, I really needed that. So I commented out the code and it works ( that was what i had originally lol). The real issue I'm worrying about is how to properly delete a client and remove their address. Should I just post another question with my remove logic?

Comment: Well, in that case you keep the cascading delete that removes and address when the client is removed. Just not the other way around (don't delete a client just because an address is deleted.) - or are you saying that the cascading delete doesn't work? E.g., you delete a client but the address record is out there orphaned?